# Not getting click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

Thanks in advance.
My html contains:

```
    <div class="help-link">
       <a href="">WHY?</a>
   </div>
```

and

```
    <div class="modal-container">
    <div data-id="modal1" class="status-modal modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <header>Status</header>
            <p><span class="fnt-wt-500"></span> Lorem Ipsum is simply 
                      dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p><span class="fnt-wt-500"></span> Lorem Ipsum has been 
                     the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
            <p><span class="fnt-wt-500"> </span>Various versions have 
                     evolved over the years, sometimes by accident.</p>
            <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
                <a href="#" class="close">OK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-backdrop">
  </div>
```

JQuery code is like

```
       $(document).ready(function() {


        $(".help-link a").click(function(e) {
            console.log("help link a clicked ");
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").hasClass("open")) {
                $(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").addClass("open");
            } else {
                $(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").removeClass("open");
            }
             });
         });
       }
```

But I am not able to log event for the click on help-link a. Please help.
Did I miss something in jquery?

Comment: Did you link jQuery Library and also is there any error in console. And I think you need to open that modal form right?

Comment: Your code is perfectly workable only last '}' you need to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra curly braces at the end of this function

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $(".help-link a").click(function(e) {
        console.log("help link a clicked ");
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").hasClass("open")) {
            $(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").addClass("open");
        } else {
            $(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").removeClass("open");
        }
         });
     });
   **}**
```

Remove it and it will work

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra "}" at the end of your code please remove it and then try

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra curly bracket you should get rid off. The below link shows the console log:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwOYqX?editors=1011

working jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".help-link a").click(function(e) {
        console.log("help link a clicked ");
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").hasClass("open")) {
            $(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").addClass("open");
        } else {
            $(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container").removeClass("open");
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra bracket at the end. Also, I have used `on()` instead of just `click()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".help-link a").on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("help link a clicked ");
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalContainer = $(".modal-backdrop, .modal-container");
    if (!modalContainer.hasClass("open")) {
      modalContainer.addClass("open");
    } else {
      modalContainer.removeClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="help-link">
  <a href="">WHY?</a>
</div>

<div class="modal-container">
  <div data-id="modal1" class="status-modal modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <header>Status</header>
      <p><span class="fnt-wt-500"></span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
      <p><span class="fnt-wt-500"></span> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
      <p><span class="fnt-wt-500"> </span>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident.</p>
      <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="close">OK</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop">
</div>
```